# JMeter - Launch Several SQL Requests

Tags: sql, jmeter

Context :
I want to load test the database but the use case is a bit larger than a single request. For instance, with the GUI we can launch a payment. This means that our software will analyse each operation running on markets, will close operation, calculate an amount, send and log payment for accountancy. Each operation has a backup in the database (for recovery, security and accountancy).

Objective :
It's a long use case but each operation is very short. I created a JDBC driver that logs each SQL operation. So I have a list of 2000ish operations that I want to replay to measure execution time.

Jmeter :
I use Jmeter to test a single request. I can setup 2 or 3 requests but I want to tests a sequence of requests as explained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your SQLs in a CSV file

Then use a [CSV DataSet](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) that will reference this file using variable sqlQuery

Then in [JDBC Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) use ${sqlQuery}

If you want the response time for the list of SQLs use [Transaction Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) as parent of all JDBC Requests

Comment: Well that's a good idea. I did not think about that. I'll try and revert to you soon.

Comment: IT works! Thanks. As a reminder for others, CSV DataSet is read in order, so my sql sequence order is ok but remeber to increase the number of execution. Also, if the order is really really important (for exemaple for key constraint), then you have to reduce the number of user to 1, otherwise JMeter send all in parallel